# error with inserting image into book down book

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

i'm trying to insert an image into my gitbook themed bookdown book, but it doesn't seem to be working. I've used the code: knitr::include_graphics("https://i.imgur.com/uy6ePN0.png"). However, instead of putting in my image, it instead shows me the attached screenshot. Am I doing this wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's going on there (you may want to include a larger code snippet), but since you are not doing anything special, simple Markdown syntax should do:

```markdown
![boolean operators](https://i.imgur.com/uy6ePN0.png)
```